# Sending mp3 parameter to jwplayer via url link

Tags: parameters, mp3, jwplayer

Firstly, I must say I'm no programmer; I know enough to break existing code.

I'm trying to see if this scenario is possible. I'm not sure how to word this but I will try.

On my blog, I include a share button next to a few hundred audio files.  By clicking on the share link, someone can send a friend an email which includes the url link back to the audio file.

Rather than creating a separate page for each audio file, can jwplayer (or any other non-flash mp3 player) be configured to takes its parameter (namely the mp3 file) from the url link that was sent in the share email?

In other words, I want to create a single page (the mp3 player page) that can play a certain mp3 file (ie it takes it parameters from the url link).

I hope this makes sense.

Any pointers would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: We have some old JS Demos here - http://developer.longtailvideo.com/contributors/nyboe/, one thing you can do is try to pass in the certain file via a querystring in the url, like this - http://developer.longtailvideo.com/contributors/nyboe/JW_API_xmpl_3-2-2-0.html?http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/qyehIiBT.flv , hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Ethan, I checked out the examples in the links you provided.  I see how the file has been added to the end of the url and the source code provides the javascript.  I will play around with it and let you know how it goes.  Thanks for replying.

Comment: Hello Ethan, I got my demo to work (using the older player.swf and swfobject.js files, which I copied from the html source) but when I try to use jwplayer6, I get configuration errors.  Do you know if this can or has been done with jwplayer6 (using html5 instead of flash)?

Comment: Np. Do you have an example of where you tried JW6?

Comment: Below is my modified page based on your first reply.

Comment: Sorry couldnt add the code, too long.  Anyways, based on your first reply, after getting the old player files to work, I then replaced "swfobject.js" with jwplayer.js and "player.swf" with jwplayer.swf, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Well, with JW6 you need to use our embedder and you can't use swfobject, it is a totally different set up - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28834/migrating-from-jw5-to-jw6